# How to create an ARFF file from an array in java?

Tags: java, weka, regression, arff

I want to get the coefficients of a weighted linear regression of an x-y pair represented by two arrays in java. I have zeroed in on weka, but it is asking an 'Instances' class object in the 'LinearRegression' class. To create an 'Instances' class file, an ARFF file is needed which contains the data. I have come across solutions that use the FastVector class but that has now been deprecated in the latest weka version. How do I create an ARFF file for the x-y pair and the corresponding weights all represented by arrays in java?

Here's my code based on Baz's answer. It's giving an exception on the last line "lr.buildClassifier(newDataset)" - Thread [main] (Suspended (exception UnassignedClassException))
    Capabilities.testWithFail(Instances) line: 1302 . Here's the code -

```
public static void test() throws Exception
{
    double[][] data = {{4058.0, 4059.0, 4060.0, 214.0, 1710.0, 2452.0, 2473.0, 2474.0, 2475.0, 2476.0, 2477.0, 2478.0, 2688.0, 2905.0, 2906.0, 2907.0, 2908.0, 2909.0, 2950.0, 2969.0, 2970.0, 3202.0, 3342.0, 3900.0, 4007.0, 4052.0, 4058.0, 4059.0, 4060.0}, {19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 31.0, 103.0, 136.0, 141.0, 142.0, 143.0, 144.0, 145.0, 146.0, 212.0, 243.0, 244.0, 245.0, 246.0, 247.0, 261.0, 270.0, 271.0, 294.0, 302.0, 340.0, 343.0, 354.0, 356.0, 357.0, 358.0}};

    int numInstances = data[0].length;

    ArrayList<Attribute> atts = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
    List<Instance> instances = new ArrayList<Instance>();
    for(int dim = 0; dim < 2; dim++)
    {
        Attribute current = new Attribute("Attribute" + dim, dim);

        if(dim == 0)
        {
            for(int obj = 0; obj < numInstances; obj++)
            {
                instances.add(new SparseInstance(numInstances));
            }
        }

        for(int obj = 0; obj < numInstances; obj++)
        {
            instances.get(obj).setValue(current, data[dim][obj]);
            //instances.get(obj).setWeight(weights[obj]);
        }
        atts.add(current);
    }

    Instances newDataset = new Instances("Dataset", atts, instances.size());

    for(Instance inst : instances)
        newDataset.add(inst);

    LinearRegression lr = new LinearRegression();

    lr.buildClassifier(newDataset);             
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might help you:

```
FastVector atts = new FastVector();
List<Instance> instances = new ArrayList<Instance>();
for(int dim = 0; dim < numDimensions; dim++)
{
    // Create new attribute / dimension
    Attribute current = new Attribute("Attribute" + dim, dim);
    // Create an instance for each data object
    if(dim == 0)
    {
        for(int obj = 0; obj < numInstances; obj++)
        {
            instances.add(new SparseInstance(numDimensions));
        }
    }

    // Fill the value of dimension "dim" into each object
    for(int obj = 0; obj < numInstances; obj++)
    {
        instances.get(obj).setValue(current, data[dim][obj]);
    }

    // Add attribute to total attributes
    atts.addElement(current);
}

// Create new dataset
Instances newDataset = new Instances("Dataset", atts, instances.size());

// Fill in data objects
for(Instance inst : instances)
    newDataset.add(inst);
```

Afterwards `Instances` is you dataset.

**Note**: The **current** version (3.6.8) of Weka did not complain, even though I used `FastVector`.

However, for the **Developer** version (3.7.7), use this:

```
ArrayList<Attribute> atts = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
List<Instance> instances = new ArrayList<Instance>();
for(int dim = 0; dim < numDimensions; dim++)
{
    Attribute current = new Attribute("Attribute" + dim, dim);
    if(dim == 0)
    {
        for(int obj = 0; obj < numInstances; obj++)
        {
            instances.add(new SparseInstance(numDimensions));
        }
    }

    for(int obj = 0; obj < numInstances; obj++)
    {
        instances.get(obj).setValue(current, data[dim][obj]);
    }

    atts.add(current);
}

Instances newDataset = new Instances("Dataset", atts, instances.size());

for(Instance inst : instances)
    newDataset.add(inst);
```

Comment: Awesome This is useful. However, on coding this, I'm getting an error.

Comment: I've added the exception in the question.

Comment: @AakarGupta Similar to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112041/error-while-using-weka-api-in-java-code-class-attribute-not-set) your data has to contain a class index, so an `Attribute` that states to which class the object belongs. You haven't set this. Please consider [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it works.

Comment: Ok, the earlier error isn't there but I'm getting another exception on the same line even after setting the class index. Here's the stack trace -

Comment: Thread [main] (Suspended (exception IndexOutOfBoundsException)) 
 ArrayList<E>.rangeCheck(int) line: not available 
 ArrayList<E>.get(int) line: not available 
 Instances.attribute(int) line: 341 
 SparseInstance(AbstractInstance).attributeSparse(int) line: 91 
 ReplaceMissingValues.batchFinished() line: 189 
 Filter.useFilter(Instances, Filter) line: 682 
 LinearRegression.buildClassifier(Instances) line: 207 
 MainTest.test() line: 63 
 MainTest.main(String[]) line: 23

Comment: what we do if we have string attribute inside double attribute???????? please help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to construct an [Instances](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instances.html) object, that class overrides `toString()` to output in ARFF format. If FastVector is deprecated you could just use [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html).