# how to write my hashmap data to arff file

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka, arff

I want to clustering collection of resumes according to Education field 
so I transform the resumes (CVs) from unstructured format to semi-structure format and the I took the data from education tags,

```
<education>data data data</education>
```

the result was for each resume has a candidate concepts (education field) 
for example :

```
resume1: computer science, computer security 

resume2: CSE, Networking
```

then I convert this data to `vector space model` and store it on a hash map (depending on the occupancy of each term in the resume i.e. either in or out <1,0>)

```
resume1  [1, 0, 1]
resume2 [0, 1, 1]
```

now I want to clustering this data that, each resume contains IT field to be in the same cluster and for example Art resumes in the same cluster

I read about `Weka` that used to cluster data. However Weka just supports `arff` input formats.
How could I write my data that I stored in the hashmap in arff file??!!
and How Weka do calculation just for the numerical data i.e. (occurrence of the term in resume) to cluster the textual data i.e. (name of resumes)?!!
sorry if my questions are nonsense but I'm totally new to Weka I hope you can help me ...

### **EDIT**

I wrote my data into arff file (just the vector data) and FINALLY after I read several questions from *stack overFlow*  I'm now able to use WEKA and I apply  `SimpleKMeans` clustering and here my output

```
Instance 1 -> Cluster 4 
Instance 2 -> Cluster 0 
Instance 3 -> Cluster 0 
Instance 4 -> Cluster 0 
Instance 5 -> Cluster 0 
Instance 6 -> Cluster 0 
Instance 7 -> Cluster 3 
Instance 8 -> Cluster 0 
Instance 9 -> Cluster 2 
Instance 10 -> Cluster 4
```

My new question is

instead of viewing instance# I want to display the name of resume
If I write the resume name as an attribute besides the vector data, can I veiw the resume name instead of instance# ?? And If yes How could I do this

Comment: Where is the problem writing this data to a arff file?

Comment: mmmm yes you could say this.... I want to write my data that I stored in the hash map (each resume with its vector)

Comment: Yes, so: **do it**! ARFF is a text format, you write it like a text file - and you sure do know how to write a text file?

Comment: yes I learned about it from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723013/using-a-arff-file-for-storing-data?lq=1).... but should I write the name of resume as an attribute also so the data will be as this `0.6, 0.1, 0.0, 0.5 , resume_name` !! because I want to clustering my data so that the output will be `cluster1: CV1, CV2.... cluster2 CV4,CV7` and so on but the clustering alg. will use the numerical data?!!